# Can I use graph-api to get page-fans-country for any page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read that page_fans_country is supposed to be a public insight, but whenever I try to use Graph API, it tells me that I need a page access token. I think I'm misunderstanding something about Graph's permission structure. Is the read_access token all I need to be able to access the two public insights for a page from the Graph Explorer? Is that even possible?

Comment: I don’t think that is public any more. (And even if it was, you would have to request the Page Public Content Access feature for your app first, without that you do not get _any_ data about pages you don’t have admin access to.)

Answer (score 0):

That metric requires read_insights and manage_pages for the respective page and cannot be retrieved w/o those permissions anymore. Page Public Content Access does not suffice here. This means a page admin needs to grant your app explicit access to it.